# Would you explain the output waveform of this FM transmitter circuit?

Tags: transistors, rf, oscilloscope, radio, frequency-modulation

I build this circuit and it works. I wanted to look at the output waveform by my soundcard oscilloscope software. I would expect something like the following picture:
[image]

But the output waveform was this:

[image]

The input of the circuit was a song played from my computer. The output of the circuit (the antenna) was connected to  the input of the virtual oscilloscope. The other input of the virtual oscilloscope was connected to ground.
[image]

My questions are:

1- Why is the output waveform different from standard (or normal) FM waveform?

2- Why is the frequency 100.1 Hz only? I received the signal at 88 Mhz.

Thank you very much,

Comment: Don't you mean 880KHz?

Comment: If you want to debug this circuit, don't use a music file. Generate a tone on a known frequency with a tone generator app

Comment: What is a "virtual scope"? A software that reads from the soundcard audio input and displays it? The bandwidth (max. frequency) of the soundcard is max. ca. 20kHz. You can't expect to see a signal in the MHz range.

Comment: Your sound card oscilloscope can't pick up anything faster than 24kHz or 96kHz

Comment: The 100Hz signal could be a rectified line frequency hum (2*50Hz = 100Hz).

Comment: @laptop2d No, I mean 88 Mhz :) It is FM signal.

Comment: @laptop: 24kHz or 96kHz is probably the sampling rate, so the max. signal frequency is half of that (12kHz or 48kHz).

Comment: You will need an expensive oscilloscope for that!

Comment: On a sound card sampling at 24kHz, you can still see signals unto 24kHz, it will alias however. I don't think its relevant to this conversation.

Comment: On a good sound card with 24 kHz sample rate, there will be an anti-alias filter damping signal components above 12 kHz into oblivion. But all sound cards I know of that still have some relevance do at least 44kHz. Still way too low to receive 88Hz, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why someone hasn't answered this beats me....

Your sound card input is good for 20 kHz and maybe 80 kHz on a good sound card sampling at 196 kHz. 88 MHz is well over a thousand times too high in frequency.

Look at the time base dial on the scope picture - it goes down to 1 ms and, in 1 milli second 88,000 cycles of FM carrier would have occured.